# Publish Only Dependencies

Tags: ivy

I want to publish the dependencies of a module seperately from the jar artifact of the module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.mycompany" module="platform" />
  <configurations defaultconfmapping="release->*;compile->*" defaultconf="release">
    <conf name="release" />
    <conf name="compile" extends="release" />
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="platform-api" type="jar" ext="jar" />
  </publications>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0" />
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.6" />

    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="13.0-rc1" conf="compile" />
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="compile" />
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.6" conf="compile" />
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

For the configuration above, I want an artifact that includes guice & slf4j-api jars only, without the platform-api.jar. My current solution is to define two dependencies in the dependent module, one transitive and other not:

```
<dependency org="com.mycompany" name="platform" rev="1.0-SNAPSHOT" conf="myconf->release">
  <exclude org="com.mycompany" />
</dependency>
<dependency org="com.mycompany" name="platform" rev="1.0-SNAPSHOT" transitive="false" conf="myotherconf->release" />
```

But this solution causes problems when the third module is dependent on both of these modules, and it is just ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.mycompany" module="platform" />
  <configurations>
    <conf name="default" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
    <conf name="master"  description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
    <conf name="compile" description="Compile dependencies"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="Runtime dependencies, includes compile dependencies" extends="compile"/>
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="platform-api" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
  </publications>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile dependencies -->
    <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.6" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="13.0-rc1" conf="compile->default" />

    <!-- Runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="runtime->default" />
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.6" conf="runtime->default" />
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**Notes:**

- Note the "extends" attribute on the configurations, used to create larger sets of jars.
- I recommend remove the default configuration mapping and explicitly set a conf mapping on each depedency. Simpler and ultimately easier to understand in my opinion (less magic)

Now that your module has separate configurations for the published artifacts and it's runtime dependencies a single dependency declaration can be used as follows to map these to separate local configurations:

```
<dependency org="com.mycompany" name="platform" rev="1.0-SNAPSHOT" conf="myconf->runtime;myotherconf->master" />
```

Comment: thanks! the usage above is a textbook quality example, that enriched my vision and I came up a solution for the third module.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is actually two projects sharing the same dependencies. (and by coincidence one of them is using the other as well).

Did you consider using extends http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/extends.html with:

```
extendType="dependencies".
```

Then you would have your platform extending the the parent-ivy.xml with the dependencies. And your Other project extending the same parent-ivy.xml file for the same dependencies.

I'm not sure if this is enough. Since the configurations will play role here. But maybe it's a start.